# Why are my ggplot fill colors not showing?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've already looked at several plausible options, but none seem to address my bug. Here are the three closest I found:

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130497/change-ggplot-factor-colors)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919025/how-to-assign-colors-to-categorical-variables-in-ggplot2-that-have-stable-mappin)
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59952777/changing-ggplot2-aes-colour-automatically-assigned-to-factors)

When I create a stacked 100% horizontal barplot, the individual components show as uniform grey. I want to use `scale_color_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Paired")`, but it doesn't work. I continue getting the same output (no error messages).

[image: Frustrating Resultant Image]

This is the [data file](https://github.com/davidmvermillion/Stackoverflowdata/blob/main/Logan3.csv) and my code (none of the four fill methods shown in this block worked for me):

```
Logan <- read.csv('Logan3.csv', fileEncoding = "UTF-8-BOM")

mancol <- c("#a6cee3", "#1f78b4", "#b2df8a", "#33a02c")

Logan %>% ggplot(
  aes(x=Locations, y = Percent, Fill = Tasks)
  ) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = "stack") +
    coord_flip() +
    scale_fill_manual(values=mancol)
    #scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
    #scale_fill_manual(c("#a6cee3", "#1f78b4", "#b2df8a", "#33a02c"))
    #scale_color_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Paired")
```

Comment: Maybe just a typo? Try with `fill = Tasks` with an `f` instead of an `F`.

Comment: Can you add a subset of your data set? Call `dput(head(Logan, 10))` and paste the output at end of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @stefan said in the comments, it's just a typo: use `fill = Tasks`, not `Fill`.

Changing that fixes the problem immediately.

[image]